# jQuery: how to serialize data inside of form that are not inputs?

Tags: jquery, serialization

using `serialize()` I have no problems to serialize the values inserted in the input text fields of a form, but..how to add to that serialized data the content of `<span>` tags that are also inside of that form?

Comment: You would need to implement it by your own, cuz no one else thought on this invention before, serialize span content... **how does that gonna work?!**

Comment: serialize what from span tags...need key/value pairs...show markup

Comment: Why would you want to serialize a span content? Wouldn't hidden form fields do the trick if you need to serialize something the user isn't able to write on the page/form?

Comment: I'm trying to do a field to add tags to an article, like the SO one for submitting new questions, but using ajax for submitting it..I didn't find any hidden field in SO one..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add the span contents to the form in hidden inputs, and then serialise the form as usual...

for html like this

```
<form id="myForm"><input type="text" name="myInput" /><span id="mySpan">this should be captured</span></form>
```

run this before serializing your form

```
$("#myForm span").each(function(i,v){
    $this = $(this)
    $("#myForm").append(
        $("<input type='hidden' />").attr({
            name:$this.attr('id'),
            value: $this.text()
        })
    )

})
```