# Serialize Slider Values into Non-Editable Text Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, serialization

I am trying to build a range slider that serializes it's values into non editable text elements like the slider seen here on http://www.padmapper.com/

I am using the noUiSlider jquery plug-in http://refreshless.com/nouislider/range-slider-form 
and I have managed to build a slider that serializes the code to input fields. My question is how do I turn the values in the input fields into non-editable text objects as in the padmapper example?

Both of the following solutions simply freeze the slider values at their start values instead of adjusting dynamically to the movements of the slider -

[jQuery: how to serialize data inside of form that are not inputs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656532/jquery-how-to-serialize-data-inside-of-form-that-are-not-inputs)

[Convert input field to text with jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337744/convert-input-field-to-text-with-jquery)

Code Below - Sorry no JFiddle - can't find a URI for the noUiSlider JS and CSS:

```
<html>

<form id="form">

<div id="slider"></div>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td> <input class="simpleCart_input" type="text" name="min-euro" id="min-euro"></td>
        <td> <input class="simpleCart_input" id="max-euro" type="text"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</form>


<js>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.nouislider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var slider = $('#slider'),
        form = $('#form');

    slider.noUiSlider({
      range: [0,8000]
      ,start: [1000,7000]
      ,connect: true
      ,serialization: {
        resolution: 0.1,
        to: [
          [ $('#min-euro')],
          [ $('#max-euro')]
        ]
      }
    });
    </script>

<css>

#slider {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

form {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto 30px;
}

table {
  font-family: Arial;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
td {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}

input, select {
  padding: 5px;
}

<!-- noUiSlider css code too long to insert -->
```

Comment: Btw: why not just disabled the inputs with `disabled="disabled"`?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. Under the serialization options for the slider, you have to add the 'html' qualifier after the id. Then change the 'input's to a spans:

```
<html>


<form id="form">

<div id="slider"></div>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td> <span id="min-euro"></span></td>
        <td> <span id="max-euro"></span> <td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">

    var slider = $('#slider'),
        form = $('#form');

    slider.noUiSlider({
      range: [0,8000]
      ,start: [1000,7000]
      ,step: 10
      ,connect: true
      ,serialization: {
        to: [
          [ $('#min-euro'), 'html'],
          [ $('#max-euro'), 'html']
        ]
      }
    });
    </script>
```